# Move base to absolute coordinates?

Tags: navigation, move-base, actionlib, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again,

I'm playing around with `actionlib` and `smach` trying to make my robot move to four specific absolute points on the map. I'm using MoveBaseGoal to drive the robot, however, it seems to accept only cordinates (i.e. the target pose) relative to the current pose (`/base_link` frame).

How do I make my robot move to an absolute point on the map (relative to the `/map` frame that is) without having to translate it from `/map` to `/base_link` everytime?

Thank you!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82721/move-base-to-absolute-coordinates?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-09-24**:
Not /map but /odom which in this case is basically the same as /map (statically the same position/orientation). I'll try using /map instead.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-09-24**:
Oh, wait, you said the target_pose... nope, that's set to /base_link. I'll try that with /map as well. Totally overlooked that... //edit: works! Thanks a lot! Sometimes it's the smallest things that have greatest influence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you setting the frame_id of the requested target pose to /map?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-09-25**:
I didn't... my bad!